# pkg_check_modules cannot find *.pc.cmake

Tags: cmake, pkg-config

I am using a 3rd party library [rbdl](https://bitbucket.org/rbdl/rbdl/src), which contains rbdl.pc.cmake, which 'I suppose' is included for using `pkg_check_modules` in a cmake file.

I update `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to point at the rbdl folder

```
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "$ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/externals/rbdl")
pkg_check_modules(RBDL rbdl)
```

but `pkg_check_modules` says it cannot find the module.

When I manually duplicate rbdl.pc.cmake, rename the copy into rbdl.pc and run `pkg-config --cflags --libs rbdl` in terminal, then my cmake also start working!

Interestingly, now even if I delete rbdl.pc, rbdl module if perfectly found by rbdl.pc.cmake!

So my questions are:

1. What is the difference between *.pc and *.pc.cmake?
2. How do I correctly setup my cmake to work with original rbdl.pc.cmake?
3. Why rbdl.pc.cmake starts to be accepted by `pkg_check_modules` after that tweak with duplicating it, renaming the copy and running pkg-config manually?

Comment: What version of CMake do you use? There were some improvement with pgk-config in CMake 3.1.

Comment: @usr1234567 I am using 2.8. Could it be the reason?

Comment: If possible, please use CMake 3.1 or newer as these version got improved pkg-config features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You understand it wrong! `rbdl.pc.cmake` is just a template file. It is not supposed to be used by you! Take a look into `CMakeLists.txt` line [160](https://bitbucket.org/rbdl/rbdl/src/cfd302b3b4189bcdce5b1f2eea1724f70f5b2851/CMakeLists.txt?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#CMakeLists.txt-160) -- [`configure_file()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/configure_file.html) used to render variables ("quoted" by `@` in template file) and produce a `rbdl.pc` (a real `pkg-config`) file. Latter should be installed (some way) and then will be available to `pkg-config` hence can be used in your project.

`pkg-config` <del>is stupid</del> do not interpret or validate compiler/linker flags any way, so your renamed file "works" (yeah, producing **invalid** command line for compiler/linker).

I wish you to read CMake documentation **before** trying to code something using it! It'll save your time and give you a necessary knowledge which stops you from doing <del>stupid</del> things like you described in your question ;-)